# How to do null/empty check of a String inside a TextFormField validator function in dart/flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, syntax, null, dart-null-safety

Is there a shorter way to check if a string is either null or empty? Do I need to write every time 2 conditions inside `if` to check it?

```
validator: (value) {
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty){
        //....
    }
}
```

In python we can do `if value` and it works. In javascript we could do `if(!value)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As from my understanding, the `TextEditingController` use `TextEditingValue.empty` which is providing empty string initially. I am not able to get null exception.

I think we can use `!` while we are sure the value is empty, not null.

```dart
validator: (value) {
  if (value!.isEmpty) return "Empty";
```

I always prefer checking null first, for nullable data type.

Comment: you can also create custom extension on String

Comment: Does this mean validator wont run if there is no value since you are using !
What if I click on a text field and do nothing and click on other text field. Does the value become '' or null?

Comment: I tried it. It will provide '' empty string and not null. But the point is we are forced to do a null check using ! even if the validator always gives empty string. I'll accept this answer for now.

Answer (score 1):

do a guard check

```dart
validator: (String? value) {
  if (value?.isNotEmpty == true) {
    return null;
  }
  
  return 'Value cannot be null or empty';
},
```

this will do, because the combination of `?.` and `== true` will check for `null`.

while the `.isNotEmpty` checks as the method's usage, if not empty.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
validator: (value) {
if (value.isNotEmpty){
     print(value);
 }else{
   print("Empty");
 }
}
```

Comment: Same issue as .isEmpty: The property 'isNotEmpty' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'. Im forced to do a null check.